# My code isn't picking up the ArrayList values in Test Class

Tags: java, unit-testing, arraylist, constructor, initialization

I am writing a code, that will calculate the area of country, it must get all values (Province areas and states areas in arraylist separate) and then add up everything.

This is the code for my Country Class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Country implements Stats {
    public String name;
    ArrayList<Integer> provincesAreas = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> statesAreas;

    public Country(String name, ArrayList<Integer> provincesAreas, ArrayList<Integer> statesAreas) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.provincesAreas = provincesAreas;
        this.statesAreas = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }

    public double computeArea() {
        double parea=0;
        for (Integer pA: provincesAreas) {
            parea = parea + pA;
        } 
        double sarea=0;
        for (Integer sA: statesAreas) {
            sarea+=sA;  
        }
        return sarea+parea;
    }
}
```

This is the Test Class Constructor

```
   Country country = new Country ("Pakistan", new ArrayList<>(List.of(21, 62, 46, 98, 67, 34, 25, 9)), new ArrayList<>(List.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)));
   System.out.println(country.computeArea());
```

The output its giving me is 362.0 but it should give an output of 398.0

How can I solve this error?

Comment: In constructor you are only initializing the array with `new` command, not setting it to `statesAreas` using `this.statesAreas = statesAreas;`

Answer (score 1):

On the fourth line of your `Country` constructor, you do not initialize `this.stateAreas` to the `stateAreas` parameter.

Your `Country` constructor should instead be:

```java
public Country(String name, ArrayList<Integer> provincesAreas, ArrayList<Integer> statesAreas) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.provincesAreas = provincesAreas;
    this.statesAreas = statesAreas;
}
```

Comment: but the instructions says that i have to initialize statesArea ArrayList in constructor

Comment: Yes, you need to set `this.stateAreas` in your constructor, as shown in the code snippet in my answer (see the last line of my code snippet above).

Answer (score 0):

You are not storing the `statesArea` parameter, but are initializing it as an empty ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

you'r not really populating the array in the constructor

```
this.statesAreas = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Comment: I tried using 

     statesArea = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Comment: sorry I was just pointing out the error.  you have to pass the variable from the constructor with that instruction you'r initializing the array as an empy one, just do this.statesArea=statesArea;

Answer (score 0):

There might be other issues with your Test Class, are you sure you're using the "List.of" method correctly?

I got an error on Eclipse.

I tried fixing your code, try this in the body of your constructor:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Country {

public String name;
ArrayList<Integer> provincesAreas = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> statesAreas;

public Country(String name, ArrayList<Integer> provincesAreas, ArrayList<Integer> statesAreas) {
    this.name = name;
    this.provincesAreas = provincesAreas;
    this.statesAreas = new ArrayList<Integer>(statesAreas);
}

public double computeArea() {
    double parea=0;
    for (Integer pA: provincesAreas){
        parea = parea + pA;
    } 
    double sarea = 0;
    for (Integer sA: statesAreas){
        sarea+=sA;  
    }
    return sarea+parea;
}
}
```